# Capture Text from tkinter entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to run the below script to capture text entered by a user into a form using tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    # create init window
    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Example Title")
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

        #submit button
        submitButton = Button(self, text = "submit", command = self.showEntry).grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 5)

        # entry widgets
        Label(self, text = "Firstname").grid(row = 0)    
        Label(self, text = "Surname").grid(row = 1)
        Label(self, text = "Age").grid(row = 2)    
        Label(self, text = "Gender").grid(row = 3)

        e1 = Entry(self)
        e2 = Entry(self)
        e3 = Entry(self)
        e4 = Entry(self)

        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        e4.grid(row=3, column=1)

    # show entries
    def showEntry(self):
        txt = e1.get()
        print("Firstname is %s" % txt)
        root.destroy()  


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root)

app.mainloop()
```

When doing so the below NameError occurs:

> NameError: name 'e1' is not defined

I am very new to tkinter, so any help in how to get the text entered by the user, and why this error is occurring would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a Tkinter issue; it's Python. `e1` is locally scoped in `init_window`. You probably want an instance variable.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: it is not `tkinter` problem but Object-Oriented Programming problem - you have to use `self.` to have access to variable in other methods in class.

Comment: BTW: common mistake `var = Widget().grid()` - this way you assign `None` to `var` because `grid()` / `pack()` / `place()` returns `None`. You have to do in two lines  `var = Widget()` and `var.grid()` or skip variable `Widget().grid()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `tkinter` but `OOP` problem.

You have to use `self.` to create variable which exists in all methods in class

```
self.e1 = Entry()
```

and later

```
self.e1.get()
```

Currently `e1` is local variable which exists only in `init_window`